# Going from closed form to recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

If I had a closed form for a sequence that I suspect to represents a recurrence relation how would I determine the recurrence relation?

In particular, I have the sequence

$$a_n = \frac{1}{4}\bigg(\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{2}\bigg)^n + \frac{1}{4}\bigg(\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{2}\bigg)^n$$

This reminds me of the closed form for the Fibonacci sequence, so I would assume that the sequence would satisfy a recurrence relation of the form $a_n = ba_{n-1}+ca_{n-2}$ for some integers (or at least rationals) $b,c$. What is a method I could use to determine the recurrence relation or determine that no recurrence relation exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose we want to find a recurrence relation such that
$a_n = \left(\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^n$ and
$a_n = \left(\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{2}\right)^n$ are both solutions, which has the form
$$
a_n -b a_{n-1} -c a_{n-2} = 0
$$
If we assume that $a_n = r^n$ for some $r$ is a solution, we'd have
$$
r^2(a_{n-2}) - br(a_{n-2}) + ca_{n-2} = 0 \implies\\
r^2 - br - c = 0
$$
So, it suffices to find $b,c$ such that $r = \frac{3}{2} \pm \sqrt{2}$ are the roots of the equation $r^2 - br - c = 0$.  The unique choice that works is
$$
b = 3\\
c = -1/4
$$
So, your sequence will be the unique solution to the recurrence problem
$$
a_n = 3a_{n-1} - \frac 14 a_{n-2}\\
a_0 = \frac 12, \quad
a_1 = \frac 34
$$

Comment: I see that this is the correct answer but why do you start with trying to find a recurrence relation such that $a_n = \bigg(\frac{3}{2} \pm \sqrt{2}\bigg)^n$ instead of one quarter of the sum of them as was the question?

Comment: Note that if $a_n$ and $a_n'$ are solutions to the recurrence $a_n = b a_{n-1} + ca_{n-2}$, then so is any combination $c_1 a_n + c_2 a_n'$.  The form $a_n = r^n$ is simply an [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz).

Comment: So by the above, it's clear that my method makes sense. The practical reason to do things this way is that $a_n = r^n$ is a much easier solution to work with directly.